# Problems restoring to multiple devices using Android BackupManager

Tags: android, restore, android-backup-service

I've implemented backup/restore of `SharedPreferences` using `BackupManager` as per the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html), but I'm having trouble restoring preferences to a second device.  I believe the implementation is fine, since I can restore settings to a single device, i.e. if I run the app, make changes, uninstall and reinstall I get the modified preferences that I expect.  However, if I subsequently install the app on a **second** device, I don't see the changes, even if I use the `bmgr tool` to force a backup on the first device and force a restore on the second device.  Both devices have the same Google accounts, and both devices successfully restore their own backed up preferences on reinstall.  I just can't get them to restore changes made from a different device.

If I install the app on a new device, I would expect it to restore the latest preferences, never mind from which device the backup was made.  I've also set the `android:restoreAnyVersion="true"` flag, but that made no difference.  What am I missing? If the devices use different transport services, could that cause the problem I'm seeing?

Comment: I have the same question, it's really not clear from the docs if sharing the backup data between devices is supposed to be supported.  It certainly would be nice.

Comment: I was looking for the same answer and found this [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42245/google-backup-multiple-devices-using-the-same-account-what-happens-on-restore#answer-49425)