# Android Backup on Multiple Devices

Tags: android, android-backup-service

*Update*: OK, so 10 hours passed and I am running the same code again on both devices, and amazingly it seems the backup and restore operations are running fine now. It must be a good day for me today.

The procedures I used to reproduce the backup and restore scenario:

1) I exported my backup app APK with the release key in Eclipse.
2) I uninstalled my backup app on both Desire S and Galaxy S2.
3) I cleared all backup data on both devices by disabling and re-enabling backup.
4) With Desire S connected to USB debugging, I confirmed that no restore set is stored in my account with "adb shell bmgr list sets".
4) I disconnected Desire S from USB, installed my backup app on it.
5) I run the backup app, which calls backupmanager.datachanged() method.
6) I connected Desire S with USB debugging, forced the backup operation to start by running "adb shell bmgr run".
7) I confirmed that a restore set is created with "adb shell bmgr list sets".
8) I installed my backup app on the Galaxy S2, and the backup created in Desire S is automatically restored.

I would be testing further to see if this procedure could be reliably reproduced, especially when I am not forcing backup operation.

---

I am writing a simple backup program that could backup and restore a small file on an Android device. I have completed nearly everything required (such as writing a custom BackupAgent) and the backup and restore operations run smoothly on the same device.

However, when I attempted to perform backup and restore across two devices, i.e. backup on one device and restore on another, the restore operation simply failed. It did not recognize the backup I created. I then tried to backup and restore the same file on both devices (but the files contain different contents). I found that the two devices backup and restore independently.

I have read that the BackupManager service on Android is intended to backup data on a device and restore when the user changes to another device. This process obviously involves two different devices. How come the backup and restore functions could not work across two devices?

I am aware of multiple questions that are similar to mine, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932372/problems-restoring-to-multiple-devices-using-android-backupmanager) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258075/android-backupmanager-not-restoring-after-uninstall-or-other-devices). Unfortunately I don't think they contain answers useful to me.

May I know if there is anyone who succeeded in creating such apps that could backup and restore on multiple devices using the Android BackupManager service?

P.S. For your information, the two devices are HTC Desire S (Android 2.3.5) and Samsung Galaxy S2 i9100 (Android 4.1.2). Both run latest official stock ROMs. Of course they are activated with the same Google account.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you share the code?